# Do long delayed echo occur on Mars and on the Moon too?

Tags: radio

[Long delayed echoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_delayed_echo) (LDEs) are radio echoes which return to the sender several seconds after a radio transmission has occurred.

Do LDEs occur on other planets and moons too? Like for example on Mars, Moon, Venus, Titan etc.

Comment: Is your question "are they known to occur on other planets/moons ?" - which can only be answered if there is observational evidence - or is it "could they occur in theory ?" - in which case the answer will depend on which of the various possible explanations for LDEs is judged the most plausible.

Comment: Unless you are Einstein :) Given the sporadic nature of LDEs, looking for them on the moon, Mars or elsewhere in the solar system sounds like a complicated experiment with a low chance of success, and so unlikely to have been funded. But that's just my opinion. Maybe someone else will come up with actual observations.

Comment: Most possibilities seem to need either a magnetosphere and/or an atmosphere.

Comment: Radio echoes were first observed in 1927 by a civil engineer and amateur radio operator. That probably means you don't need a high power transmitter in order to try it. And that means that it's quite possible to test it on the Moon or on Mars

Comment: Now I wonder if it occurs in space like from ISS or from satellites. Maybe I should open another question for that?

Answer (score 1):

If you accept the idea that an LDE is caused by radio waves being guided around the planet several times by the diffractive effects caused by the ionosphere, then you need an ion source high in the atmosphere and ultraviolet light to perform the ionization work on it.

For this reason, a planet without an atmosphere (like the moon) wouldn't support LDE's, and a planet with an atmosphere but without UV radiation from a nearby star wouldn't either.